# Jess rule definition

Tags: protege, jess

I use the Jess Rule Engine in Protégé.

I need to create a test rule using classes, I defined in Jess code.
Here are classes & instances definition code:

```
(clear)
(defclass Student
    (is-a :THING)
    (slot studId (type string))
    (slot studName (type string))
    (slot satGrade (type integer))
)
(defclass Course
    (is-a :THING)
    (slot courseId (type string))
    (slot courseName (type string))
    (slot passGrade (type integer))
)
(defclass StudentInCourse
    (is-a :THING)
    (slot studId (type string))
    (slot courseId (type string))
    (slot finalGrade (type integer))
)

(make-instance stud_01 of Student (studId "s123") (studName "Rob") (satGrade 650))
(make-instance stud_02 of Student (studId "s456") (studName "Pete") (satGrade 700))
(make-instance stud_03 of Student (studId "s789") (studName "Alex") (satGrade 770))
(mapclass Student)
(deffacts Student (Student (studId)(studName)(satGrade)))
(make-instance course_01 of Course (courseId "c123") (courseName "Calculus") (passGrade 60))
(make-instance course_02 of Course (courseId "c456") (courseName "Linear Algebra") (passGrade 70))
(mapclass Course)
(deffacts Course (Course (courseId)(courseName)(passGrade)))
(make-instance studInCourse_01 of StudentInCourse (studId "s123") (courseId "c123") (finalGrade 20))
(make-instance studInCourse_02 of StudentInCourse (studId "s123") (courseId "c456") (finalGrade 90))
(make-instance studInCourse_03 of StudentInCourse (studId "s456") (courseId "c123") (finalGrade 80))
(make-instance studInCourse_04 of StudentInCourse (studId "s789") (courseId "c456") (finalGrade 75))
(mapclass StudentInCourse)
(deffacts StudentInCourse (StudentInCourse (studId)(courseId)(finalGrade)))
```

Now I want to implement a check who among the students passes the course «Linear Algebra», I know how to implement it in SQL/Java/C#, but I can't understand how exactly to write it in Jess, each string I push to Jess returns a parsing/compilation error.

How exactly to implement kind of `join` in Jess or pass over the collection, get `courseID`, to compare the values according to `ID` and `passGrade`/`finalGrade`, for the correct values to retrieve the data from the student class and as the result to return something like: «Pete passed course Linear Algebra with grade 80»?

Comment: The facts in the deffacts aren't asserted until you call ( reset). If you're not doing that, insert it right before the (run).

Comment: I completely rewrote the question.

Comment: Are you asking about how to do some particular task, or are you asking about the compilation error ("but I can't understand how exactly write it in Jess, each string I push to Jess returns with parsing/compilation error.")?  If you're asking about the latter, then it would be good to provide the error that you're getting.  If you're asking about the former, and "[you] know how to implement it in SQL/Java/C#," then it would be helpful if you'd provide some implementation in one of those languages so that we have a better idea what you're _trying_ to do.

Comment: I'm asking about how to do some particular task. About implementation example, in SQL you can do it with select, join & where according to IDs with logical condition regarding to the passGrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been ages since I touched Protege, but based on what you have above, I'm assuming you have facts like these (among others). The "deffacts" you have above must be notional at this point -- they won't do anything good (and may not even parse).

```
(Student (studId "s123")(studName "Rob")(satGrade 650))
(StudentInCourse (studId "s123") (courseId "c456") (finalGrade 90))
(Course (courseId "c456") (courseName "Linear Algebra") (passGrade 70))
```

Given that I'm right about the above, then a rule that reported each student who passed any course might look like

```
(defrule passed-algebra
    (Course (courseName ?cn) (courseId ?cid) (passGrade ?pg))
    (StudentInCourse (courseId ?cid) (studId ?sid) (finalGrade ?fg&:(>= ?fg ?pg))
    (Student (studName ?name) (studId ?sid))
    =>
    (printout t ?name " passed course " ?cn " with a grade of " ?fg crlf))
```

Comment: Do I understand right, “deffacts” here is unwanted here? It seems I actually don't fully understand the aim of “deffacts” statement. Can you explain it, please, because I don't get it clearly from http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/jess/language.html

Comment: Wow, that is an *ancient* copy of the Jess documentation; it was already ancient when the book "Jess in Action" came out ten years ago! The current documentation is here: http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/index.shtml

Comment: In any case: `deffacts` is used to define a list of facts; they're added to working memory when you call `(reset)`. Protege's "JessTab" adds a layer on top of Jess; `make-instance` and `mapclass` effectively do the same thing, and so `deffacts` is not needed here. You can either define facts with make-instance, or with deffacts, but it's not necessary (or correct) to do both.